# How to using subquery values in arithmetic operations

Tags: sql, sql-server

My manager wants to see what is total values of our suppliers shipments, and what is the total values of their invoices recorded. So he can see the differencies and want from suppliers to unsended invoices.

Here is my code.

It is working on accounting table and shipment detail table.

`fis_meblag0` is always little from zero because it is 320 account so I mutiply it -1 for get real value.

`sth_tutar` is value of shipment, `sth_vergi` is VAT and so the sum of them is equal to sum of total with VAT.

Now the hard part.

Manager wants to diference between them in a other column and also sort the valuez z to a.

I know I can reuse same subselect for the getting totals but I want to know that can I achieve this without using the same subquery again.

I mean in first subselect I have the total, in last column I only need just the total, can I use total without compute it again?

Regards

```
select 
    ch.cari_kod as Carikod,
    ch.cari_unvan1 as Unvani,  
    (select (sum(mf.fis_meblag0) * -1) 
     from dbo.MUHASEBE_FISLERI mf 
     where (mf.fis_tarih > '20141231' and mf.fis_tarih < '20150201')
       and mf.fis_hesap_kod = ch.cari_kod
       and mf.fis_meblag0 < 0) as mtoplam,
   (Select sum (sth.sth_tutar + sth.sth_vergi) 
    from dbo.STOK_HAREKETLERI sth 
    where (sth.sth_tarih > '20141231' and sth.sth_tarih < '20150201') 
      and sth.sth_cari_kodu = ch.cari_kod
      and sth.sth_normal_iade = 0
      and sth.sth_tip = 0) as stoplam 
from 
    dbo.CARI_HESAPLAR ch
where 
    ch.cari_kod like '320%'
```

Comment: It can be great if we can use in last column just "(mtoplam-stoplam) as Grand_total.

Comment: I know about it but i dont use it in real environment. i know we can write UDF but subquery is faster than UDF. I have tried it before with a different problem and subselects has better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query:

```
select Carikod, Unvani, mtoplam, stoplam, mtoplam - stoplam as Grand_total
from
(
    -- your full query here
) T
```

Comment: Wowww that is working like a charm. You are great... I also use the stoplam in order by clause and it is worked